# wordpress, Category ID

Tags: php, html

I have created an Id category in primary menu in homepage when I click it redirect good to the second section I have selected . All I wan't to know, is it possible from another page this Category Id to redirect to homepage in the second section?

Thank you

Comment: And this second section of yours is where?

Comment: vipfash.com homepage (menu- page categories ) second section